# Why does h2 ignore slf4j messages on the first connection when LOG is set?

Tags: h2

See sample code & output below (with Slf4j/logback on stdout). I can't find any bug reports on this. I'm using h2 version 1.3.176 (last stable), in-memory mode. It doesn't seem to matter what value is set for the LOG (0, 1 or 2) but just has to be set.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class H2TraceTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        System.out.println("Query connection 1");
        Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:mem:tracetest;TRACE_LEVEL_FILE=4;LOG=2");
        myConn.createStatement().execute("SELECT 1");

        System.out.println("Query connection 2");
        DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:mem:tracetest").createStatement().execute("SELECT 1");

        System.out.println("Query connection 1 again");
        myConn.createStatement().execute("SELECT 1");

        System.out.println("End");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Query connection 1
Query connection 2
16:17:02.955 INFO  h2database - jdbc[3] 
/**/Connection conn2 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:mem:tracetest", "", "");
16:17:02.958 DEBUG h2database - jdbc[3] 
/**/Statement stat2 = conn2.createStatement();
16:17:02.959 DEBUG h2database - jdbc[3] 
/**/stat2.execute("SELECT 1");
16:17:02.959 INFO  h2database - jdbc[3] 
/*SQL #:1*/SELECT 1;
Query connection 1 again
End
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that the [H2 documentation](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#set_trace_level) says about `TRACE_LEVEL_FILE`: *it affects all connections*. But thats not (fully) correct:

Every connection keeps a lazy reference to the logging system. And if you change that with the special marker `TRACE_LEVEL_FILE=4`, then that reference isn't changed for all existing connections - but only for those who do their first logging after that change.

So if you use the connection string `"jdbc:h2:mem:tracetest;TRACE_LEVEL_FILE=4"` everything is as expected, because your session will write no logging message before changing the logging system. Unfortunately the `LOG=2` in `jdbc:h2:mem:tracetest;TRACE_LEVEL_FILE=4;LOG=2` is evaluated first, because both parameter are written into and read from an unordered `Map`. And because `LOG=2` is generating a log statement, the reference to the log adapter (=4) is never applied to the current session. Only to the next one.

What can you do:

- Use only `"jdbc:h2:mem:tracetest;TRACE_LEVEL_FILE=4"` - `LOG=2` is the default anyway. If you need any other log mode you can use `connection.createStatement().executeUpdate("SET LOG 1")`
- Add some default parameters to the connection string until the `TRACE_LEVEL_FILE` parameter is the first parameter in the map (not really reliable, as the order may depend on the VM)
- Discard the first connection at once
- Fill in a bug report and wait for the fix (or fix it yourself), as I think this is somehow a bug

Comment: The problem is specific to slf4j. I redirect slf4j messages to stdout so we can see whats going on clearly.

According to the docs, trace level is applicable to all connections. http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#set_trace_level

Log level, LOG=2, is different from debug output, which is controlled by the trace level.

Comment: The problem is specific to `TRACE_LEVEL_FILE=4` in combination with `LOG=2` - see my update.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but here is a reliable way to do it (i.e. you can ensure that `TRACE_LEVEL_FILE` is set to `4` first:

```
String url = "jdbc:h2:mem:tracetest;INIT=SET TRACE_LEVEL_FILE=4\\;SET DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1/* for example, i.e. do other stuff */";
```